# adding objects to arrayList in android is not working

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to add Objects to my arraylist but its not working and its giving me

> "Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
>     - Syntax error on token "a", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this    token"

```
ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();  
Record a = new Record ("Math","Add","Due Date is", "20/12/2011"); 
Record b = new Record ("Science","biology","Due Date is ", "21/12/2011"); 
records.add(a);
records.add(b);
```

Comment: Please supply more context - where is this code? inside a method? outside a method?

Comment: The problem is not with adding to ArrayList rather than with instantiating objects. Can you please provide more information about the Record class?

Comment: Its an syntax error, it has nothing to do with the list.

Comment: no its not inside any method ! this code is right after i declared the class and extended the Activity

Comment: The class Record is a normal class , 4 string variables . one constructor that initialize those variables , getters and setters

Comment: you should check your Recode class constructor

Answer (score 2):

You need to put those calls to `ArrayList.add()` into a method!

See the answers to this question: [What does the "Multiple markers" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991458/what-does-the-multiple-markers-mean)

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in `onCreate()` of Activity.