# What does the “Multiple markers” mean?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to use in the following way:

```
@Override
public User getModel() {
    return user;
}
```

And I get the following error message generated by Eclipse:

Multiple markers at this line

- The method getModel() of type UserAction must override a superclass method
- implements com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven.getModel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips

Comment: Did you try searching for [Multiple Markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991458/what-does-the-multiple-markers-mean) before posting?

Comment: What is your class definition? class Clazz extends ModelDriven<UserAction> ?

Answer (score 3):

It means that there are multiple problems at that line. One of which is the fact that you can't use `@Override` if a method with the same signature does not exist in the superclass.