# error in caling a method. (java)

Tags: java

in this program I want to show pascals triangle using users' input. but there is an error. what is the error in calling pascaltriangle method? (the error says, multiple markers at this line). How can I fix this? thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pascal{
    static int userinput=0;
static Scanner myscanner= new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    prln("give pascals' triangles length:");
    int userInput=myscanner.nextInt();
    if(userInput>0){
            pascalstriangle(userinput);
    }
}


    static void pascalstriangle(int a){
        int pascal[][]= new int[a][a];
        for(int c=0;c<a;c++){
            pascal[0][c]=1;
            pascal[c][0]=1;
        }
        for(int row=1;row<a;row++){
            for(int column=1;column<(a-row);column++){
                pascal[row][column]=pascal[row-1][column]+pascal[row][column-1];
            }
        }
        for(int row=1;row<a;row++){
            for(int column=1;column<(a-row);column++){
                pr(pascal[row][column]+"\t");
            }
            prln("\n");
        }

    }




public static void pr(Object cop)   {
    System.out.print(cop);
}
public static void prln(Object c6op)    {
    System.out.println(c6op);
}

}
```

Comment: It means there are more problems on that line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991458/what-does-the-multiple-markers-mean. Make sure to attach those errors to your question.

Comment: what do you expect from your code give us a example tnks

Comment: i want a user input and then pascals triangle from it. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Here I found some problems in your code.

1. Instead of

   ```
   pascal[row][column]=pascal[row-1][column]+pascal[row[column-1];
   ```

use

```
pascal[row][column]=pascal[row-1][column]+pascal[row][column-1];
```

2. check `main()` method closing braces.
3. check class closing braces.

Not only these. some more problems are there..

Comment: checked, yet not working,,, the  "multiple markers at this line" error is before this line  >>                       static void pascalTriangle(int a ){

Comment: @AsifSabir pascalTriangle write this method outside of the main method.

Comment: @AsifSabir you written `pascalTriangle()` method inside `main()` method.

Comment: don't edit the original question. you suppose to update it. Otherwise it will effect to others answers.

Comment: ok. good. but both the methods `pr` and `prln` should be inside of the class. but you written outside of the class. you missed 3 rd step. @AsifSabir

Comment: again edited. no errors. but the method does not execute after giving input. would you please run it for me and check?