# Getting an "Type alt_up_character_lcd_dev could not be resolved" error

Tags: c++, embedded, nios

I've been working on try to display anything on the LCD screen using the Nios processor and the DE10-Lite board for weeks. I finally found a code that may help, but the I've been unable to shake off this error message, the code I found is

```
#include <string.h>
#include <system.h>
#include <altera_up_avalon_character_lcd.h>


int main(void)
{
 alt_up_character_lcd_dev * char_lcd_dev;

// open the Character LCD port
char_lcd_dev = alt_up_character_lcd_open_dev ("/dev/character_lcd_0");

if ( char_lcd_dev == NULL)
alt_printf ("Error: could not open character LCD device\n");
else
alt_printf ("Opened character LCD device\n");

/* Initialize the character display */
alt_up_character_lcd_init (char_lcd_dev);

/* Write "Welcome to" in the first row */
alt_up_character_lcd_string(char_lcd_dev, "Welcome to");

/* Write "the DE2 board" in the second row */
char second_row[] = "the DE10 Lite";
alt_up_character_lcd_set_cursor_pos(char_lcd_dev, 0, 1);
alt_up_character_lcd_string(char_lcd_dev, second_row);
}
```

the error is on the second line after int main(void) writing `alt_up_character_lcd_dev * char_lcd_dev;`

I'm using a DE10-Lite board, the platform designer for the connections and a 16x2 LCD OSEPP screen.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you check if `altera_up_avalon_character_lcd.h` is really included?

Comment: Try #include "altera_up_avalon_character_lcd.h" if it works.

Comment: I switch it to ""altera_up_avalon_character_lcd.h", it doesn't work.

Comment: its now saying `Multiple markers at this line, Line breakpoint: hello_world.c [line: 31], Type 'alt_up_character_lcd_dev could not be resolved`

Comment: Try `struct alt_up_character_lcd_dev * char_lcd_dev;`?

Comment: I can't [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/o1vjqW91q) you issue, which compiler are you using?

Comment: oh snap it worked I shook off the error with struct, what does struct do? lol

Comment: Using `struct` in the beginning?

Comment: How do I find out what compiler I am using? Im not sure, but I'm running it as a Nios 2 hardware

Comment: I inserted struct right after `alt_up_character_lcd_dev * char_lcd_dev;` just like you suggested, I used it in the same line.

Comment: re, the compiler - you are running it, how can you not know what you are running?  How are you building your code?

Comment: `struct alt_up_character_lcd_dev` is a type while `alt_up_character_lcd_dev` is an alias for `struct alt_up_character_lcd_dev` (via a `typedef`), it appears that your compiler does not accept the alias and the tag having the same name as valid (it is - just a bad idea - better to make it an anonymous struct, or a better naming convention).

Comment: There is probably nothing wrong with your compiler.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991458/what-does-the-multiple-markers-mean) suggest you are using an Eclipse based IDE and reporting the messages the IDE is presenting in pre-parsing your code - that is not the compiler checking your code, it is a C aware editor is clearly reporting erroneously.  Have you tried ignoring the error message and actually building the code to see what the compiler proper says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [header](https://github.com/Danny417/module2/blob/master/software/Rss232_bsp/drivers/inc/altera_up_avalon_character_lcd.h),  the `typedef` uses the same name (`alt_up_character_lcd_dev`) for both the `struct` tag and the `typedef` alias.

My assumption is that your compiler is confused by this. (but [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/Gq4WY99W1) doesn't have this issue)

To fix it,

```
struct alt_up_character_lcd_dev* char_lcd_dev;
```

might help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a compiler error; it is a message from your *C language aware IDE or code editor* (presumably Eclipse based?), and it is clearly confused (and wrong).  You can ignore it and build regardless to see what the actual compiler makes of it.  No doubt it will build just fine.

The problem is caused by the `typedef` of `alt_up_character_lcd_dev` in *altera_up_avalon_character_lcd.h*:

```
typedef struct alt_up_character_lcd_dev {
    /// @brief character mode device structure 
    /// @sa Developing Device Drivers for the HAL in Nios II Software Developer's Handbook
    alt_dev dev;
    /// @brief the base address of the device
    unsigned int base;
} alt_up_character_lcd_dev;
```

Note that both the the typedef alias and the struct tag are both `alt_up_character_lcd_dev` and your code editor is confused by that even though it is entirely valid.  You can handle the "problem" in several ways, including:

- Ignore it, it will compile anyway.
- Remove the struct tag to make `alt_up_character_lcd_dev` and alias to an anonypous `struct`:

  ```
  typedef struct {
    ...
  } alt_up_character_lcd_dev;
  ```
- Ignore the type-alias and specify the type `struct alt_up_character_lcd_dev` everywhere you use it - gets a bit "wordy".